# How to create symbolic link for non-existing folder?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to create link to a folder on desktop of remote computer. I do not have permissions to execute scripts on that computer, but I can copy files to that computer.

My idea was to create link to folder on local computer and then copy the link to remote computer. 
But, I am getting error `New-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\SomeFolder' because it
does not exist.`

Here is my command:

```
New-Item -Path "c:\Users\pocherka\Desktop\link" -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value "c:\SomeFolder" -Force
```

Any ideas for workaround?

Comment: Make the folder path, create the symlink, delete the folder path? Did you try using the `-Force` switch?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I think he can't create/delete a folder on the computer because of access rights. But I think `-Force` will do the trick.

Comment: `-Force` did not work. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using *mklink* also . Make sure that the destination folder is available . You can use the Test-Path to check that :

```
$destination = "c:\SomeFolder"
if(Test-Path $destination)
{
cmd /c mklink "c:\Users\pocherka\Desktop\link" $destination
# OR you can use the new-item also. Just commented in the below line
# New-Item -Path "c:\Users\pocherka\Desktop\link" -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $destination
}
else
{
New-Item $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
cmd /c mklink "c:\Users\pocherka\Desktop\link" $destination
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `-force` parameter:

```
New-Item -Path "c:\Users\pocherka\Desktop\link" -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value "c:\SomeFolder" -force
```

Comment: Apologies that I couldn't actually test this, since I can't access the `-ItemType SymbolicLink`.